# When laptop lid is opened, Debian login screen shows up instead of Windows login - how to re-instate?

Tags: windows-7, debian, grub, multi-boot

I installed Debian beside Windows 7 in my laptop. I had an issue with GRUB not recognizing the Windows partitions at first, which I could fix by running grub-update (this found the windows partitions, but placed them at the end, AFTER the Debian install).

The laptop is configured to "Sleep" when I close the lid when logged in to Windows, and used to show me the Windows Login screen when re-opened. Now when I re-open it, it shows me the Debian login screen instead! And it does not even show the usual booting screens for Debian, even if it was shut down. I am forced to hit Restart, and choose to boot to Windows 7. It says "Resuming Windows" and again Windows starts *without showing the boot screens*! My problem is that when I login now, all my windows were closed, and any unsaved data is lost.

What I want is when I open the Lid, the right OS should show, namely the one I was logged in to when I closed the lid. Right now, a quick fix would be to choose the option *Do Nothing* when closing the lid, but this will stress the system as it will be forever on (sorry, too lazy to shut down start up everyday!) - so is there a better solution?

**EDIT, UPDATE**: I found that it is not "Sleep" that is the problem, but "Hibernate".The computer is fine if I open the lid a few minutes within closing - but when I leave it overnight, I think it "Hibernates" and *that* is causing the problem.

**EDIT, UPDATE 2**: Well, I am also wrong about the windows all closing up. Even if I restart from inside Debian, the System maintains all data when it hibernated... so apart from a little restart pain, nothing is really wrong. I think I should research on changing boot priorities for GRUB...

Answer (score 1):

I remember having a similar problem when I used to dual boot Windows/Ubuntu a few years ago... I'm pretty sure I had to edit the grub boot file.

I did a quick search on changing the default boot OS, the question below might be of some help.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/82928/how-to-make-windows-boot-first

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll check that link out - by the way, please see the update I added to the question...